# How to serve react app with pm2 server in https with a valid SSL certificate that I have?

Tags: ssl, create-react-app, pm2

I am trying deploy a React-App(backend = python) chatbot with pm2 serve. I have valid SSL certificate files from digitalocean. I use the following commands to serve.

```
npm run build
pm2 serve build 3000 --spa
```

But this opens in http url only.
How to serve with pm2 in https using certificates. is there any command to do it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this one. This worked for me.

```
pm2 start --name front "HTTPS=true SSL_CRT_FILE=../certs/certificate.crt SSL_KEY_FILE=../certs/private.key npm" --start
```

Comment: getting following error for this [PM2][ERROR] Process or Namespace HTTPS=true SSL_CRT_FILE=../a/config/key.cert SSL_KEY_FILE=../a/config/key.key not found